# Pad size of power jack

Tags: surface-mount, footprint, pad

I want to use a DC power jack in my circuit, and I chose [this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1864271.pdf). Since Eagle does not have this schematic, I have to draw it on my own. Unfortunately I do not understand the pad size dimensions. It tells me that it should have the dimensions "4-3.0x2.0". Which size does that mean? In Eagle I have the option to use the size "3.81x1.9304", which sounds as the best variant. Is that correct?

Comment: Usually I would recommend tth dc jacks unless there are really good other reasons to use smt.

Comment: Then I have the problem that I do not know how to create 2mm-holes (or the suitable slit form) in eagle.

Comment: I assume "4-3.0x2.0" means 4 terminals with "3.0x2.0" dimension, because there are other things with the same notation and the count does add up to what it says.

Comment: @machineaddict: This size does not exist in eagle either.

Comment: "3.0x2.0" means width x height. It surely can be created. I don't use Eagle, but that pad size can be done. And don't forget the extra space for soldering.

Comment: @machineaddict: How much do I have to add for soldering?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: What is the advantage of TTH jacks compared to smt jacks?

Comment: @arc_lupus: physical stability. If you ever had one  in your hands because your kid pulled at the cable you know what I mean.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Well, this one is designed for building into a case which surrounds the jack, therefore I think there is less danger of ripping it off.

Comment: @arc_lupus: Just don't let kids play with it. They always find a way to destroy the indestructible.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Letting kids play in a lab with two active 20W-lasers? Well, I am going to worry about a lot other stuff before I am worrying about them destroying the pcb...

Comment: @arc_lupus: it depends on many factors, one which is how skillful you are with the soldering and how robust you want the solder to be. If I would do it, 1mm around the pad would be ok with me, so the new dimension of one pad would be 5.0x4.0

Comment: @arc_lupus: I once ran into a dog down in the DESY tunnels, so never say never ;) Also mind the decaffinated coworker at 5am in the morning

Comment: @machineaddict: It will be machine-soldered. Do I still need some additional space around?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use the **exact** nominal pad dimensions and spacings shown on the datasheet. You might have to set the grid differently or something like that on Eagle (not a user) but I'm sure you can do it. See any tutorial on creating SMT parts from scratch.

Presumably you're going to use two **2mm holes** for the **location posts** (even though one of the posts is actually designed to fit a 1.6mm x 2mm elliptical shape (probably about 1.3 x 1.7mm). I would suggest you specify those holes as unplated so the pins fit nicely. You might even make them a touch smaller than recommended if you're using hand assembly. The unplated designation may result in a slight cost increase in the PCB because it requires an extra process step. Sometimes folks nail down the connector with a bit of epoxy to make it more sturdy (eg. the SMT mini-USB connector on the Beagleboard).

As others have said, the through-hole connectors are much more sturdy than the SMT ones (even with the location posts), but it's better if you can use drilled slots for the tabs. Large holes work okay for hand soldering, but they suck up a lot of solder.